# Android Recyclerview same item layout changes after certain number of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to give the possibility to select multible items in a recyclerview. If the users clicks on a item I do following to change the background color of the item:

```
relativeLayout = viewHolder.rL;
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 224));
```

this works fine, but after 10 items the item is also grey. If I change `setItemViewCacheSize()` to for example 100 this problem doesn't occur. But I am not shure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recycler view reuses the same views for the different items. So you have to store selection state not only on the UI level.

Comment: Thanks, so do I have to set the background color every time a new item is loaded?

Comment: Yep, you have to set appropriate background color when you bind a view to the item in your view holder.